# Request a key from web.config to a .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

The Scenario:

i have in web.config in appSettings a key:

```
<add key="stylet" value="http://localhost/style.css"/>
```

i have an .cs file with the following code:

```
response.ContentType = "text/html";
response.Write("<html>");
response.Write("<head>");
response.Write(@"<title>See the page</title>");
response.Write(@"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
response.Write("</head>");
response.Write("<body>");
response.Write("<br /><table style='width: 500px'>");
response.Write("<tr><td class='ArticleIntro'>");
response.Write(propertyValue);
response.Write("</td></tr>");
response.Write("</table>");
response.Write("</body>");
response.Write("</html>");
```

The Question:

How do i request the key in the .cs file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class for this:

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stylet"];
response.Write(@"<link href='"+ value +"' type='text/css' />");
```

Comment: When i am writing the code this ConfigurationManager is not appear in my intellisense. Why?

Comment: i have using System.Configuration; added

Comment: You should reference System.Configuration.dll

Comment: If you referenced an System.Configuration.dll and added using for System.Configuration it should work.

Comment: Sorry sir my mistake i had 2 projects and this one particularly it didn't had the reference. Is working now